# get id of a hyperlink inside datalist using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a datalist and inside it there is a dropdown list and hyperlink which is loaded dynamically,means if there is one user then there will be one dropdown and one hyperlink and 
there are two users then there will be two dropdown and two hyperlink.My requirement is when an onchange event occurs in a dropdown i want the id of the hyperlink assosiated with that dropdown in javascript.Can any one help me please.

thanks

Comment: Show us what the dynamic HTML looks like please?  We can't guess what it looks like.

Comment: i want to know how to get id of a hyperlink inside datalist using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Control.ClientIDMode` property

Possible values:

- AutoID
- Static
- Inherit (default)
- Predictable (used in data-bound scenarios) This is the value that you should use

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ddlChanged(sender) {
        var senderID = $(sender).attr("id");
        var idSplitted = senderID.split("_");
        var currentHyperLinkID = "dl_hl_" + idSplitted[2];
        var currentHyperLink = $("#" + currentHyperLinkID);

        alert(currentHyperLink.text());
    }
</script>
    <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dl" ClientIDMode="Predictable" DataSourceID="ods">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" onchange="ddlChanged(this);">
                <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionText") %>' ID="hl" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

This will cause that all child controls will generate client ID's using this format:

```
            <select name="dl$ctl00$ddl" id="dl_ddl_0" onchange="ddlChanged(this);">
        <option value="text1">text1</option>
        <option value="text2">text2</option>

    </select>
            <br />
            <a id="dl_hl_0" href="http://www.google.com">QuestionText1</a>
```

For example:

```
dl_hl_0
```

Where:

- *dl* is the name of the `DataList`
- *hl* is the name of the `HyperLink` control
- ##. This will be a unique number generated for all bound controls inside the `DataList`, the same number for all controls in each row

NOTE: You should consider using the `ListView` control instead of the `DataList` control. The latter is a legacy control and does not have all the characteristics exposed by the `ListView`.

For example, there is a property called: `ClientIDRowSuffix` that is used to insert a primary key as part of the Client ID. This property is not available in the `DataList` control